# How to break a long URL in bibliography, keeping the URL in plain text font?

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

I am preparing a paper for a journal which insists that URLS in bibliography need to be in plain text (and not in the style that `\url{long_url_here}` provides). A URL that I am using is very long and continues in the same line without breaking to next line. I know that it breaks when I use `\url{}` command, but not when I just use a note in the bib file such as:

```
@misc{epl,
title={Premier league clubs in international competition},
author="{Wikipedia}",
year={2016},
note="{Available at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier\_League#Premier\_League\_clubs\_in\_international\_competition, Accessed on December 26, 2016}",
}
```

My preamble is

```
\documentclass{risa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
```

I am using `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}` and I use `risa` document class available from: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/%28ISSN%291539-6924/homepage/ForAuthors.html. Download link: http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/pdf/risa.zip.

Also, I do not understand why I have to use backslashes before the underscores in the URL, despite using the quotations before and after the opening and closing braces respectively for `note={}` in the bib file.

Any help on figuring out the problems here is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: @Mico Vancouver.

Comment: @Mico I am including that in the question as well.

Comment: The `url` package provides the `\urlstyle` declaration to set the style used for printing the URL; for example, `\urlstyle{same}` “uses the current text font” (documentation of the `url` package, section 3).  You might also want to have a look at the `\DeclareUrlCommand` declaration (described in section 4) and to section 5 of the same manual.

Comment: @Mico: Yes, obviously, thanks for noting. :-)  But I see that you were already writing an answer along these lines, so I should probably remove my comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

URL strings can contain lots of characters that are "special" to TeX. Among them are `_` (underscore), `#` (hash), `%` (percent), `$` (dollar), `&` (ampersand), etc. The point of encasing URL strings in `\url` directives is to "neuter" the special meanings that these characters would otherwise possess.

> I am preparing a paper for a journal which insists that URLs in bibliography need to be in plain text.

I assume that the ordinary text font (rather than some monospaced font) is meant by "plain text". This requirement does *not* mean that you mustn't use the `url` package and `\url` directives. All you need to do to adhere to the publisher's requirement is issue the instruction `\urlstyle{same}`. The advantage of not "escaping" the special characters (by prefixing them with `\` symbols) is that the URL strings remain untouched and hence can be used to form valid hyperlinks to the underlying documents.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{epl,
title={Premier league clubs in international competition},
author="{Wikipedia}",
year={2016},
note="{Available at: \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League#Premier_League_clubs_in_international_competition}, Accessed on December 26, 2016}",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{risa}
%\usepackage{natbib} %not really needed, is it?
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same} % <-- be sure to provide this instruction
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{epl}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. I looked into the `url` package documentation too, for more details.

Answer (score 4):

`urlstyle{rm}` should be enough in most cases. See the example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url} 
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{1}
\url{VeryVeryVeryVery.VeryVeryVeryVeryVery.VeryVeryVeryVery.VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongUrl}

\urlstyle{rm}
\bibitem{2}
\url{VeryVeryVeryVery.VeryVeryVeryVeryVery.VeryVeryVeryVery.VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongUrl}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** According to Mico's suggestion, one additional explanation. The manual states:

> The pre-defined styles are “tt”, “rm”, “sf” and “same” which all
>   allow the same linebreaks but use di.erent fonts — the first three select a specific
>   font and the “same” style uses the current text font.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't `same` a better choice than `rm` if the latter is a specific font?

Comment: @VineetPayyappalli I understand your "plain text" as roman, not typewriter. Am I wrong?

Comment: @PrezmyslawScherwentke yes it's plain text.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke - You may want to add a sentence to explain the (potential) difference between `\urlstyle{same}` and `\urlstyle{rm}`.

Comment: @VineetPayyappalli See the extended version of my answer. As far as I understand, the only reason  of avoiding `url` package is the policy of a journal, which doesn't want the typewriter font.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke that's great. The journal doesn't have a policy to avoid `url` package, instead, the policy is that URLs must be in plain text. When I posted the question, I felt there is no solution to the problem if I use `url` package, which is why my initial question was "How to break a long URL in bibliography without using \url or related packages." Perhaps the "without using \url or related packages" part does not make sense any more?

Comment: @VineetPayyappalli I think, incorporating this information by editing your original question will be enough.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I just edited my question title, does that sound better sense now?

Comment: @VineetPayyappalli Yes, it preserves keywords and states the real problem.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Great!